# Laravel Redis Jobs are not Being Queued

Tags: php, laravel, redis, jobs, phpredis

I am using Laravel with Phpredis and I've created a webhook that adds a job to the queue. I've followed the docs for the interrogation but my jobs are not being queued.

.env

`QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis`

config/database.php

`'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),`

config/queue.php

```
...
'connections' => [
    ...
    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => null,
     ],
    ...
],
...
```

I am using Windows with Xampp and redis-server.exe is running. This is what I am getting when the job is being added to the queue:

```
[9672] 03 Nov 21:44:03 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:52945
[9672] 03 Nov 21:44:03 - Client closed connection
```

This is how I'm adding the jobs to queue:

```
ProcessPhotos::dispatch($settings, $data, $id);
```

And this is how I'm trying to run the queued jobs:

```
php artisan queue:work
or
php artisan queue:listen
```

I am running one of the previous commands and nothing is happening and I'm also not receiving any errors. It's like the queue is empty (I've also checked the queue length using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412779/how-to-get-all-pending-jobs-in-laravel-queue-on-redis/54937580#54937580) and I've got `000`).

I've also tried to set a key into redis and that seemed to work. Does somebody know what's happening? I'm thinking to move to database if i can't get this solved ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the issue!

It turned out that it was **something wrong with the server**. (I've reinstalled again the Redis extension and it still wasn't working, then I changed the server version and it was working)

I reinstalled the Redis extension from [here](https://gist.github.com/wuliupo/c2831fc7c6a48c48cc5da03ddf2446da) and switched to [this](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases/tag/win-3.0.504) server version. The rest of the settings were the same as in my previous post.